# How to use python to log on Nike+ website?

Tags: python, web

Here's the link: http://nikeplus.nike.com/plus/
The email/password option only shows when I click "Log in" button. So how to use python to log into this website?

I tried twill and got the forms on the page but it includes only the search bar. So not sure how to proceed

Comment: Generally, I've had to use selenium to log in to sites like that. It's lame.

Comment: use httpfox and see what posts and gets you discover. after that just use the requests library to get what you need

Comment: What are you trying to `get` after you login successfully?

Comment: The user data of fuelband

Comment: Anything found on this? I am also looking at how to access the nike+ login URL from code.

https://api.nike.com/nsl/v2.0/user/login

This url is the login url which is being called from the "Get access token" form submition on developer API console page. But, i am not able to figure out the appropriate request format as this is internally handled...

Answer (score 0):

While not a python solution, I wrote a PHP class that actually lets you get the data from the Nike+ website: https://nikeplusphp.charanj.it

The class works by faking the login on the website and then makes requests to the feeds. If you look through the code you'll find all the URLs to make the necessary GET requests and there is a method called `_login()` and this should give you an idea of what parameters are posted.